# Convert std::vector<T> to char *

Tags: c++

I'm trying convert vector to char * for send by socket
the type of T is a simple struct

```
struct CategoryStruct {
    int ID;
    char name[32];
};

std::vector<CategoryStruct> categories;
```

Function, where I'm trying to convert -

```
char * Category::decodeCategoryToCharArray()
{
    int structSize = sizeof(CategoryStruct),
        currentByte = 0,
        i = 0;

    if(decoded)
        delete [] decoded;

    decoded = new char[structSize * categories.size()];
    std::vector<CategoryStruct>::iterator start, end;

    start = categories.begin();
    end = categories.end();

    for(; start != end; start++, i++)
    {
        memcpy(decoded+currentByte, &categories[i], structSize);
        currentByte += structSize+1;
    }

    return decoded;
}
```

End return will be ""

Comment: You can simply copy whatever `categories.data()` returns directly with `memcpy`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: You don't need to convert anything, pass `categories.data()` to `send` or `write` directly.

Comment: I try use memcpy(decoded, categories.data(), getCategorySize()); but it still not work. I need to convert for send this data with headers

Comment: what doesnt work if you do this?

Comment: If something doesn't work, show your error messages or actual program output together with the desired output. Read about [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for *conversion*, `std::vector<CategoryStruct>` already stores the data in a contigous memory area. so your function could be boiled down to

```
std::vector<CategoryStruct> categories;
char * Category::decodeCategoryToCharArray()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(categories.data());
}
```

Comment: I still get "" but categories contains 2 items

Comment: @Pavel Well, that might have other reasons, be assured that `std::vector` isn't the source of your problem. You may try to provide us with a [MCVE] in your question, so that someone can help. An easier and faster way to go would be to debug your code line by line.